# Left principal eigenvector in scipy or numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to find the principal left eigenvector of a matrix. How can I do this with numpy or scipy?

Answer (score 2):

Using the eigendecomposition of the transpose for example.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randn(10, 10)
v, V = np.linalg.eig(A.T)
```

Then `left_vec = V[:, 0].T` is your vector. Test it by evaluating

```
print left_vec.dot(A)
print left_vec * v[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`scipy.linalg.eig`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html) with `left=True` and `right=False`.